# Decomposition of a group into disjoint double cosets

Tags: group-theory

This is taken from Lang's *Algebra*, exercises on groups.

Let $G$ be a group and $H,H'$ be subgroups of $G$. A double coset of $H,H'$ is a subset of the form $HxH'$, $x\in G$. The first question asks to prove that "$G$ is a disjoint union of double cosets."

Well, we have $G = \coprod_{g\in G} \{e\}g\{e\}$, but I guess this is not what Lang expected to see as an answer. So let us take two subgroups of $G$, $H$ and $H'$ and define the action $\rho: H\times H' \rightarrow \mathfrak S_G$ defined by $\rho(h,h') = (x \mapsto hxh'^{-1})$. Hence the orbit of an element $x$ is $HxH'$, and taking $X$ as a set of representatives of the orbits, $G = \coprod_{x\in X} HxH'$.

Is this the "expected (canonical) answer"? Are there other "canonical" decompositions into cosets?

Comment: The exercise is asking to prove that for *any* subgroups $H$ and $H'$ (not special ones that we select like $H=H'=\{e\}$), we have $G$ is a disjoint union of double cosets $HxH'$ (only $x$ is varying, not $H$ and $H'$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

Prove that

$$R\subset G\times G\;,\;\;(x,y)\in R\iff \;\exists \;h\in H\;,\;h'\in H'\;\;s.t.\;\;x=hyh'$$

is an equivalence relation on $\,G\;$ , and thus $\;G\;$ is the disjoint union of this equivalence relation's equivalence classes.

Now, what are the equivalence classes? :)

Comment: Doesn't this give rise to the same decomposition I gave?

Comment: Perhaps it does, but that was not the question, imo, but rather whether what you did is the "expected" answer. Of course, I can't tell one way or another, and I just offered an elementary approach, without actions of groups and stuff but only basic set theory.

Answer (score 0):

By the use of actions, let $H$ acts on $G/H'$ via $(h,aH')\to h\cdot aH'$, so you get for an orbit 
$$HaH'=\{hak\in G: h\in H,k\in H'\}.$$
The set of orbits gives the partition 
$$G=\bigsqcup_aHaH'.$$ 
Then one can define the relation
$$a\sim b\quad \mbox{iff}\quad HaH'=HbH'$$
which is the same equivalence relation fore mentioned.